# "ok" button missing in iOS7 with Cordova on "select prompt"

Tags: html, cordova, ios7

I got a Cordova IOS7 APP where I have a default HTML "select" -

When the select prompt shows there is NO "ok" or "done" button to close it again, in iOS6 it works fine, and the same with the buildin Safari browser.

So, can anyone tell me what the problem is?

**Cordova APP**
[image: Cordova APP]

**Safari browser**
[image: Safari browser]

Comment: Are you using a plugin to show the select prompt, or relying on the native implementation?

Comment: It's the native - "or" the Cordova way- don't know why the OK button is gone i my webview.. :(

Comment: Are you able to share your code? At least the html (+ JavaScript if it's generated)

Comment: The code is all standard HTML - a "select" with some "options" - thats what I don't get.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i got it.

Simple answer -

Set this to "false"

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/select-dropdown-issue-on-ios/5573/3

Answer (score 1):

You can show and hide the accessory bar on demand which is [explained better here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-select-options-and-ios-keyboards/17210/5?u=patrickmcd) (but it worked better for me by taking out the $timeouts in the directive). Here's what mine looks like.

```
.directive('select', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('focus', function(e) {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          // console.log("show bar (hide = false)");
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function(e) {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          // console.log("hide bar (hide = true)");
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```